# Laravel Middleware not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I have following code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;

class CheckLogin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Session::has('userAuthDetail')){
            // return redirect('login');
            // return redirect()->guest('/login');
        } else {
            return $next($request);     
        }
    }
}
```

in web.php

```
Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);

Route::group(['middleware' => ['login']], function () {
    Route::post('/add','MyController@submitData');
});
```

Login Controller

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
     //    print_r($request->all());

     $data['email']=$request->email;
     $data['password']=$request->password;
     $response=  ApiModel::userLogin($data);
     if($response->msg=='success'){
         session(['userAuthDetail' => $response->data[0]]);
         return redirect('/');
    } else if($response->msg=='failed'){
         return redirect('/');
    }   
}
```

if i add if else condition in middleware then website throwing error

> ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 156: Trying to get property
>   of non-object

if i remove if else and add just

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   if(!Session::has('userAuthDetail')){

   } 
   return $next($request);      
}
```

then working fine but if credentials failed then its redirecting to dashboard.

Note: i cant use laravel auth since i am communicating with the api which is written in core php

Updated;

kernal.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckLogin::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'login' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckLogin::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: have you define poslogin function route in middleware?

Comment: @kunal .no its outside of login middle route

Comment: How did you register the middleware in the Kernel.php file?

Comment: 'login' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckLogin::class, in route middleware and in middleware group web

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov.updated question

Comment: you have define LoginController@login in web.php and use the Postlogin function in controller ?

Comment: i have defined both Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
Route::post('/post-login','Auth\LoginController@postLogin'); controller in web.php but not inside login middleware group

Answer (score 0):

you should return to your login page if user session is not created as

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!Session::has('userAuthDetail')){
         //return to login page
    } 
    return $next($request);//if session exist then forward the request     
}
```

Comment: ya i have already tried that but  if i add that then website pages are not responding

Answer (score 0):

[Line 156 of VerifyCsrfToken.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b2d9b4697f2a295a86697f0ae7648f2dbcae1beb/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#L156) shows that it attempts to call `$response->headers->setCookie(...)`. Your error indicates that $response is null, and that is what would happen in your CheckLogin middleware in the `if(!Session::has('userAuthDetail')) { ... }` scenario.

Basically, you have a middleware that is returning null (or nothing at all, which kind-of is treated as null in the PHP world). This is not allowed, a middleware must always return a response of some kind (or throw an exception).

**TL;DR:** Your middleware must return a response for all execution paths.